# bootstrap to get confidence intervals using R

Tags: r, statistics-bootstrap

Im trying to bootstrap reliability estimates using non parametric bootstrap
I have written the code below where a model is created and then bootstrapped 1000 times in order to get two reliability statistics Alpha and Omega
I am able to get the Alpha and the Omega for the first construct with confidence intervals: `visual  =~ x1 + x2 + x3` but see no way of accessing it for the other constructs `textual` and `speed`
When i run the boot function, i see results for all of them

```
# bootstrapping with 1000 replications
results <- boot(data=data, statistic=reliability, R=500, formula=HS.model,parallel = 'snow')

> results$t0

        visual   textual     speed     total
alpha  0.6261171 0.8827069 0.6884550 0.7604886
omega  0.6253180 0.8851754 0.6877600 0.8453351
omega2 0.6253180 0.8851754 0.6877600 0.8453351
omega3 0.6120052 0.8850608 0.6858417 0.8596204
avevar 0.3705589 0.7210163 0.4244883 0.5145874
```

Below is my admittedly shoddy attempt. Can anyone help

```
library(lavaan)
library(semTools)
library(boot)

data <- HolzingerSwineford1939

HS.model <- 'visual  =~ x1 + x2 + x3
textual =~ x4 + x5 + x6
speed   =~ x7 + x8 + x9 '

# function to reliability stats
reliability <- function(formula, data, indices) {
  data = data
  d <- data[indices,] # allows boot to select sample
  fit <- cfa(HS.model, data=d)
  semTools::reliability(fit)
}

# bootstrapping with 500 replications
results <- boot(data=data, statistic=reliability, R=500, formula=HS.model,parallel = 'snow')

# Get the confidence intervals
conf_interval_alpha <- boot.ci(results, type="bca", index = 1)

# Retrieve the Alpha and confidence intervals
alpha <- conf_interval_alpha$t0
alpha.ci <- conf_interval_alpha$bca[,c(4,5)]

# Retrieve the Omega and confidence intervals  
conf_interval_omega <- boot.ci(results, type="bca", index = 2)
omega <- conf_interval_omega$t0
omega.ci <- conf_interval_omega$bca[,c(4,5)]
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Basic debugging ... do this in fresh session ...and  READ error messages. The first error I encountered was:   Error in ERsum(beta[i, ], tau.found.sym.optim, m + 1, m + n) : 
  dims [product 666] do not match the length of object [999]
In addition: Warning message:
In y - X %*% beta :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Comment: Sorry, yes, i see it now. I will update the code straight away

Answer (score 0):

You first need to look at what is returned from `reliability` with the full dataset:

```
> reliability(data=data)
          visual   textual     speed     total
alpha  0.6261171 0.8827069 0.6884550 0.7604886
omega  0.6253180 0.8851754 0.6877600 0.8453351
omega2 0.6253180 0.8851754 0.6877600 0.8453351
omega3 0.6120052 0.8850608 0.6858417 0.8596204
avevar 0.3705589 0.7210163 0.4244883 0.5145874
```

Then you need to see what is returned from your `boot`-call:

```
> str(results)
List of 11
 $ t0       : num [1:5, 1:4] 0.626 0.625 0.625 0.612 0.371 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:5] "alpha" "omega" "omega2" "omega3" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:4] "visual" "textual" "speed" "total"
 $ t        : num [1:500, 1:20] 0.594 0.607 0.613 0.669 0.621 ...
 $ R        : num 500
 $ data     :'data.frame':  301 obs. of  15 variables:
  ..$ id    : int [1:301] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 11 ...
  ..$ sex   : int [1:301] 1 2 2 1 2 2 1 2 2 2 ...
  ..$ ageyr : int [1:301] 13 13 13 13 12 14 12 12 13 12 ...
  ..$ agemo : int [1:301] 1 7 1 2 2 1 1 2 0 5 ...
  ..$ school: Factor w/ 2 levels "Grant-White",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
  ..$ grade : int [1:301] 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 ...
  ..$ x1    : num [1:301] 3.33 5.33 4.5 5.33 4.83 ...
  ..$ x2    : num [1:301] 7.75 5.25 5.25 7.75 4.75 5 6 6.25 5.75 5.25 ...
  ..$ x3    : num [1:301] 0.375 2.125 1.875 3 0.875 ...
  ..$ x4    : num [1:301] 2.33 1.67 1 2.67 2.67 ...
  ..$ x5    : num [1:301] 5.75 3 1.75 4.5 4 3 6 4.25 5.75 5 ...
  ..$ x6    : num [1:301] 1.286 1.286 0.429 2.429 2.571 ...
  ..$ x7    : num [1:301] 3.39 3.78 3.26 3 3.7 ...
  ..$ x8    : num [1:301] 5.75 6.25 3.9 5.3 6.3 6.65 6.2 5.15 4.65 4.55 ...
  ..$ x9    : num [1:301] 6.36 7.92 4.42 4.86 5.92 ...
 $ seed     : int [1:626] 403 330 1346657232 1136157038 -874329217 857221657 1850455833 952027245 2020402269 -1198488986 ...
 $ statistic:function (formula, data, indices)  
  ..- attr(*, "srcref")=Class 'srcref'  atomic [1:8] 1 16 6 1 16 1 1 6
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "srcfile")=Classes 'srcfilecopy', 'srcfile' <environment: 0x7fa57918d430> 
 $ sim      : chr "ordinary"
 $ call     : language boot(data = data, statistic = reliability, R = 500, formula = HS.model, parallel = "snow")
 $ stype    : chr "i"
 $ strata   : num [1:301] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ weights  : num [1:301] 0.00332 0.00332 0.00332 0.00332 0.00332 ...
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "boot"
```

.... so `results$t0` has all three model parameter estimates in it.

Comment: Hi @42-, thank you for reply. I am able to pull the `omega` and the `alpha` point statistics but i also want to get the confidence intervals which  im not able to see when i run the code `boot.ci(results, type="bca", index = 1)` for all three constructs; `visual`, `textual` and`speed`

Comment: Read the help page for `?boot.ci` and pay particular attention to the "index" parameter. With the default values you only get the CI estimate for the first parameter.